# How to change fade InOut timing in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, fade, fadeout

Below is some jQuery to fade in and out list items sequentially. This code makes the list items fade in and out very fast. How do I control the speed?

```
function InOut( elem ) 
 {
elem.delay()
 .fadeIn()
 .delay()
 .fadeOut( 
           function(){ 
               if(elem.next().length > 0)
               {InOut( elem.next() );}
               else
               {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));}

             }
         );
}

$(function(){
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first'));

});
```

Thanks for your help.

Angela

Comment: Read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete).

Comment: Q. How do I do something with jQuery method `x()`? A. Read the jQuery documentation for method `x()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in a number in milliseconds too the `fadeIn` `fadeOut` functions.

```
fadeIn(300); // 300 milliseconds to fade in
fadeOut(1000); // 1 second to fade out
```

In your case you would do something like;

```
function InOut( elem, fadeIn, fadeOut ) {
    elem.delay()
    .fadeIn(fadeIn)
    .delay()
    .fadeOut(fadeOut, 
       function(){ 
           if(elem.next().length > 0)
           {InOut( elem.next(), fadeIn, fadeOut );}
           else
           {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'), fadeIn, fadeOut);}

         }
     );
}

$(function(){
     $('#content li').hide();
     InOut( $('#content li:first'), 1000, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut takes 2 parms, the duration, and a handler.

```
$(selector).fadeOut(4000, function(){
//do something
});  for example
```

your fadeIn just needs the first parm,

```
$(selector).fadeIn(4000)
```